# Booting different kernel from U-Boot based on time stamp

Tags: kernel, mips, bootloader, u-boot

I am using U-Boot and two kernel Image(uImage). I want to add some code in U-Boot which will select kernel based of time stamp.
I am using MIPS architecture.
this two kernels are in different MTD partition.

For example:-

```
If kernel-1 is new, U-Boot will boot Kernel-1. and leave kernel-2 as it is.
If kernel-2 is new, U-Boot will boot kernel-2. and leave kernel-2 as it is.
```

Questions:-

```
Is it possible to do so?
How can I add such functionality in U-boot?
Where to chage the code for the same?
```

Comment: You probably would create a new U-Boot command (that could partially retrieve each uImage and compare the embedded uImage creation timestamps) for use in the `bootcmd` variable/macro.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following applies to what you are trying to do.

Please see the [DULG page](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/HowCanIImplementAutomaticSoftwareUpdates) on implementing automatic software updates in U-Boot.

It has links to a [README](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.update) which explains the details of implementation and the [commit](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commit;h=4bae9090) which implements it.

This approach is based on update files instead of time-stamps.
Quote from the README:

> The update file should be a FIT file, and can contain one or more
>   updates. Each update in the update file has an address in NOR Flash
>   where it should be placed, updates are also protected with a SHA-1
>   checksum. If the TFTP transfer is successful, the hash of each update
>   is verified, and if the verification is positive, the update is stored
>   in Flash.